# jira extention of TwoDimensionalStatsResource and using estimated time is shown in seconds not in days

Tags: plugins, jira, jira-plugin

I have a class in my jira custom plugin that extends TwoDimensionalStatsResource in order to have estimated time that we can summarize, not only the number of the issues.

This is a gadget that we use in the dashboard.

The implementation is something like (in the class that extends jira TwoDimensionalStatsResource from jira-gadgets-plugin-ul-6.3.12.jar):

```
public class TwoDimensionalTimeStatsResource extends TwoDimensionalStatsResource { ....

 /*** Overriden from {@link com.atlassian.jira.gadgets.system.TwoDimensionalStatsResource} so that the function populateStatsMap} can be called */
protected TwoDimensionalStatsMap getAndPopulateTwoDimensionalStatsMap( StatisticsMapper xAxisMapper, StatisticsMapper yAxisMapper, SearchRequest searchRequest) {
    TwoDimensionalStatsMap statsMap = new TwoDimensionalStatsMap(xAxisMapper, yAxisMapper);
    populateStatsMap(searchRequest, statsMap);
    return statsMap;
}
....

private void populateStatsMap(SearchRequest searchRequest, TwoDimensionalStatsMap statsMap) {
  Collector aCollector = new TwoDimensionalTermHitCollector(statsMap, issueIndexManager.getIssueSearcher().getIndexReader(), fieldVisibilityManager, readerCache, fieldManager.getNavigableField( IssueFieldConstants.TIME_ESTIMATE).getSorter());
  try { searchProvider.search(searchRequest.getQuery(), authenticationContext.getUser(), aCollector);
 } catch (SearchException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e);}
}
```

**The problem:**
I have the time estimate shown in seconds rather than in days and minutes like it's shown in the issue search.
The filed that we use is: "timeestimate"
We are using jdk1.7.0_45 and jira-6.3.12.

I know that in jira 5 it worked at some point, showing days, not seconds.
It should show 4d or 3h, not 345600 or 10800

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JiraDurationUtils, getFormattedDuration to convert seconds to days/hours format:
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/latest/com/atlassian/jira/util/JiraDurationUtils.html#getFormattedDuration(java.lang.Long)